# Find the Record with Null Values and Display the Column Names using Unix2

Tags: unix, awk

I have following Input file and need to find which field has null and Display the Key Column and Null Value Column Name.

Note : In Future There might be New Fields can be added.

Input.txt

```
Keyfeild1|Over|Loan|cc|backup
200|12||0|
100||15|1|200
100|100|100|100|100
50||50||11
```

ExpectedOutput.txt :

```
200|Loan
200|backup
100|Over
50|Over
50|cc
```

Command Used :

```
{cat Input.txt | awk -F"|" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i=="") { print $1"|"i} }'}
```

Achieved Output:

```
200|3
200|5
100|2
50|2
50|4
```

Comment: No need use `cat` with `awk`, `awk` is capable of reading the Input_file(s) by itself. Also please use CODE TAGS for your sample shown in your post/comments.

Comment: Please do not post same question twice.

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk -F"|" 'FNR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){a[i]=$i};next} {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){if($i==""){print $1,a[i]}}}' OFS="|"   Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now:

```
awk -F"|" '
FNR==1{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    a[i]=$i};
  next
}
{
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i==""){
      print $1,a[i]}}
}
' OFS="|"   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
200|Loan
200|backup
100|Over
50|Over
50|cc
```

Comment: `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){a[i]=$i}` = `split($0,a)`.

Answer (score 1):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" }
     NR==1{ split($0, a); next }
     { for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) if ($i=="") print $1,a[i] }' file
```

The output:

```
200|Loan
200|backup
100|Over
50|Over
50|cc
```